# Phoenix prompts to run a migration that doesn't exist

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Let's describe the problem:

- I created a new phoenix app with `mix phx.new`
- I configured a database connection within `{dev, test}.exs` (I'm mapping an existing database)
- I created a context using `mix phx.gen.context` (which created a migration)

I tried running the server for the first time but it told me that I have undeployed migrations.

```
there are pending migrations for repo: Some.Repo. 
Try running `mix ecto.migrate` in the command line to migrate it
```

Then I realized I don't need them since I already have the database so I deleted the migration file (`/priv/repo/migrations/*`) and tried again.

Now `mix ecto.migrations` show nothing, but it did not remove the server prompt. Then I found that ecto creates an additional table in the database for the migrations so I checked it and it was empty.

I dropped it and tried running the server again but the same message was shown.

---

To make sure it's not an Ecto problem I've prepared tests and they run just fine, the only problem is the migration prompt shown when I run the server.

---

I don't have any endpoints yet since I was planning to use GraphQL after I've verified that the models are working but that message is confusing.

Are there any hidden files for that migration or am I missing something else?

Stacktrace:

```
[error] #PID<0.451.0> running Some.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.449.0>, stream id 1) terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Phoenix.Ecto.PendingMigrationError) there are pending migrations for repo: Some.Repo. Try running `mix ecto.migrate` in the command line to migrate it
        (phoenix_ecto 4.2.1) lib/phoenix_ecto/check_repo_status.ex:67: Phoenix.Ecto.CheckRepoStatus.check_pending_migrations!/2
        (phoenix_ecto 4.2.1) lib/phoenix_ecto/check_repo_status.ex:27: anonymous fn/3 in Phoenix.Ecto.CheckRepoStatus.call/2
        ...
[error] #PID<0.454.0> running Some.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.449.0>, stream id 2) terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /favicon.ico
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Phoenix.Ecto.PendingMigrationError) there are pending migrations for repo: Some.Repo. Try running `mix ecto.migrate` in the command line to migrate it
        (phoenix_ecto 4.2.1) lib/phoenix_ecto/check_repo_status.ex:67: Phoenix.Ecto.CheckRepoStatus.check_pending_migrations!/2
        (phoenix_ecto 4.2.1) lib/phoenix_ecto/check_repo_status.ex:27: anonymous fn/3 in Phoenix.Ecto.CheckRepoStatus.call/2
        ...
```

#### UPDATE

After further investigation it seems that the project somehow stores the first ever migration generated by `mix phx.new.context`.

Whenever I re-create the database it prompts for the migration of this very context. I don't have any files mentioning that migration in my project.

Comment: What does `Ecto.Migrator.migrations(Some.Repo)` return for you?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov `[{:down, 20201111101131, "create_person"}]`

Comment: As i feared this problem doesn't allow me to test the api.

Comment: Did you try to find this mysterious `create_person` migration? Look [here](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/v3.5.3/lib/ecto/migrator.ex#L171) - to me it looks like a migration path can be configured per repo, so please check what `Some.Repo.config()[:priv]` gives you - chances are your migration sits somewhere in the different location...

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov I've managed to solve this by dropping the tables and running the prompted migration. When I re-created the database afterwards it did work. I imagine though that it would be a major problem in other circumstances. Right now `Some.Repo.config()[:priv]` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this problem and it was only resolved by deleting the `_build` folder, nothing else worked, not `ecto.reset` nor deleting the migrations table. Elixir must be storing some state relating to migrations in the project somewhere.

```
rm -rf _build/
```

Answer (score 4):

run mix ecto.migrations This will show you the migrations you have. This list will (hopefully) match the list in /priv/repo/migrations.
Go to _build/<your_app_name>/priv/repo/migrations and delete the files from here that are not in the other two migration lists.
It seems to have worked for me

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly for me on a new project connecting to an already established database.